# Printing out max and average with one function

Tags: c++

Combine max and average into a single NEW function that “returns” both the maximum and the average of a set of entered numbers. Use a single function to this.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

double maxAverage(double& max, double& average);
int main()
{

  maxAverage(max,average);

  return 0;
}

double maxAverage(double& max, double& average)
{
  double val = 0;
  double total = 0;
  double count = 0;


  cout<<"Please enter a value, or -1 when you're done."<<endl;
  cin>>val;
  while(val!=-1){
    total+=val;
    count++;
    cout<<"Please enter a value, or -1 when you're done."<<endl;
    cin>>val;
    if(val>max)
      max = val;
  }
  average = total / count;
  return average;
  return max;
}
```

I have an error when calling the function and not sure really how to this problem this is what I have so far.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Marceline averageMax.cpp:9:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'average'
  maxAverage(max,average);

Comment: `max` is not defined as well in `int main()`

Comment: Once the code hits a return the function is done. You can't return multiple values by having more than 1 return.

Comment: Neither is `average` in `main()`.

Answer (score 4):

### Approach 1: Using by-ref (`&`) parameters correctly:

You need to declare `max` and `average` before the call-site, and pass them by-reference:

```
double max = 0;
double average = 0;

maxAverage( &max, &average );
```

The `maxAverage` function does not need a return value and should be changed to `void`.

### Approach 2: Using a new `struct`

Functions are easier to reason about when they're simpler - and using return-values are simpler than using output parameters or by-ref parameters. Consider using a new `struct` to return those values.

```
struct MaxAverageResult {
    double max;
    double average;
}

int main( int argcx, char* argv* )
{
    MaxAverageResult r = maxAverage();
    cout << r.max << " " << r.average << endl;
    return 0;
}

MaxAverageResult maxAverage()
{
    // etc

    MaxAverageResult r;
    r.max = max;
    r.average = average;
    return r;
}
```

The syntax is simpler in C++11 with Uniform Initialization:

```
MaxAverageResult maxAverage()
{
    // etc

    return { max, average };
}
```

### Approach 3: Using `std::tuple<T1,T2>` (aka `std::pair<T1,T2>`):

This approach is identical to the above, but instead of declaring a new `struct MaxAverageResult` you use `std::pair` and the `make_pair` function:

```
int main( int argcx, char* argv* )
{
    std::pair<double,double> r = maxAverage();
    cout << r.first << " " << r.second << endl;
    return 0;
}

MaxAverageResult maxAverage()
{
    // etc

    return std::make_pair( max, average );
}
```

Comment: should I make it a void function?

Comment: @user12230466 I would go with the `std::pair<T1,T2>` approach used by @Marceline and not use `ref` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can not return two values from a function so returning them as `std::pair` makes sense.

Full implementation would be:

```
std::pair<double,double> maxAverage(double& max, double& average)
{
  double val = 0;
  double total = 0;
  double count = 0;


  cout<<"Please enter a value, or -1 when you're done."<<endl;
  cin>>val;
  while(val!=-1){
    total+=val;
    count++;
    cout<<"Please enter a value, or -1 when you're done."<<endl;
    cin>>val;
    if(val>max)
      max = val;
  }
  average = total / count;
  std::pair<double,double> p;
  p.first = average;
  p.second = max;
  return p;
}
```

Calling `maxAverage` function needs to be like this:

```
std::pair p =  maxAverage(max,average);
double average = p.first;
double max = p.second;
```

Comment: This does not fix the `max` and `average` not being defined in `int main()` Also if you return these as a pair what is the point of the two reference parameters?

Comment: I just wanted to show returning two values in the same time. Op have more than one problem and i did not give attention to another problems.